# Python regular expression match not working

Tags: python

I have written below given code to match a string of fixed length of 10 which contains all digits.

```
import re
result=re.match("^d{10}$", u"5478512045")
```

But it returns None. I don't know why is it failing. Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an escape `\` on the `d` control character.  It should be:

```
result=re.match("^\d{10}$", u"5478512045")
```

Without the `\` before the `d`, your regex is trying to match a literal `d` string.  By changing this to `\d` you match against the special character for any decimal digit.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I am now getting return value as "<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02A27138>". Please tell me how do I check if it has passed or failed.

Comment: `result.group()` will print the result of the match.  The fact that you have `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02A27138>`, however means that you have a match.

Comment: @dsilver1221 is correct.  The fact you get an object back means you have a match.  Getting 'None' returned (as before) means no match.  Check the documentation for the 're' module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match), it's pretty comprehensive.